# Mongoose, mongodb, bad aggregate grouping

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I m actually trying to get some information concerning my app.

I have to get some informatiogrouping by day / month / year. I have the good result attributes, but information is displayed even if there is nothing in DB.

*NB : Start and End are good formatted dates.*

```
TraitementNettoyage.aggregate([
      {$match: { 'dateEntre': {$gt: start}, 'dateEntre': {$lt: end} }},
      {$group: {'_id': {'day': {'$dayOfMonth': '$dateEntre'}, 'month': {'$month': '$dateEntre'}, 'year': {'$year': '$dateEntre'}}, count: {$sum: 1}}}
    ]).exec((err, res)=>
console.log res
)
```

And I get this resultset :

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "day": 24,
            "month": 3,
            "year": 2015
        },
        "count": 2
    }
]
```

The fact is that I have nothing in DB concerning the 2015-03-24.
In my DB, I have only 2 sets of data with the 2015-03-23 date.

What should I correct in my request to get the exact two resultsets :

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "day": 24,
            "month": 3,
            "year": 2015
        },
        "count": 0
    }
]
```

and

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "day": 23,
            "month": 3,
            "year": 2015
        },
        "count": 2
    }
]
```

?

EDIT :

Here the resultset with $lte and $gte :

```
[
    {
        "_id": {
            "day": 25,
            "month": 3,
            "year": 2015
        },
        "count": 2
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "day": 24,
            "month": 3,
            "year": 2015
        },
        "count": 2
    }
]
```

The problem is that the count are not correct. in fact it should be 2 for 24/03/2015 and 0 for 25/03/2015.

Thanks for advance

Comment: Have your start and end date containing from 23/3/2015 or 24/3/2015?

Comment: 23/03/2015 to 23/03/2015 and 24/03/2015 to 24/03/2015. The problem is that the count is not correct in fact :-/

Comment: please use $gte and $lte as well.

Comment: I edit my post, so you can see the result

Comment: Hi, can you show me pls start and end vars

Comment: Can you show us the 2 documents that you claim aren't processed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

split the $match for dateEntre

```
TraitementNettoyage.aggregate([
      {$match: { 'dateEntre': {$gte: start}}},
      {$match: { 'dateEntre':  {$lte: end}}},
      {$group: {'_id': {'day': {'$dayOfMonth': '$dateEntre'}, 'month': {'$month': '$dateEntre'}, 'year': {'$year': '$dateEntre'}}, count: {$sum: 1}}}
    ]).exec((err, res)=>
console.log res
)
```